# Saving plot as pdf and simultaneously display it in the window (x11)

Tags: r

I have written a function that creates a barplot. I would like to save this plot as a pdf as well as display it on my screen (x11) when applying this function. The code looks like this.

```
create.barplots <- function(vec)
 {
   x11()                                  # opens the window
   ### Here is a code that creates a barplot and works perfectly
   ### but irrelevant for my question
   dev.copy(pdf("barplots.table.2.pdf")) # is supposed to copy the plot in pdf
                                         # under the name "barplots.table.2.pdf"
   dev.off()                             # is supposed to close the pdf device
 }
```

This creates the following error: 'device' should be a function

When I modify the code to:

```
create.barplots <- function(vec)
 {
   x11()
   ### Here is a code that creates a barplot and works perfectly
   ### but irrelevant for my question
   dev.copy(pdf) # This is the only difference to the code above
   dev.off()
 }
```

R displays the plot and creates a file called Rplots.pdf. This is a problem because of several reasons.

I also tried to open the devices the other way around. First open the pdf device, than copy the content of the pdf device into the x11 device, than set the pdf device as active and than close the pdf device. The code here looks like this:

```
create.barplots <- function(vec)
 {
   pdf("barplots.table.2.pdf") # open the pdf device
   ### Here is a code that creates a barplot and works perfectly
   ### but irrelevant for my question
   dev.copy(x11)              # copy the content of the pdf device into the x11 device
   dev.set(which = 2)         # set the pdf device as actice
   dev.off()                  # close the pdf device
 }
```

The problem here is that the wondow that is supposed to display the plot is empty!

To sum up, I have two questions:
1) How to save a plot as pdf and display it in x11 simultaneously? And
2) How to save the plot not in the working directory somewhere else?

*EDIT*

The solutions above work great. But I still do not understand why

```
pdf("barplots.table.2")
barplot(something)
dev.copy(x11)
```

displays an empty grey window instead of copying the content of the pdf device in the window device! I also tried

```
pdf("barplots.table.2")
barplot(something)
dev.copy(window)
```

In which I failed as well...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

How about:

```
create.barplots <- function(...) {
  x11()
  plot.barplots(...) # create the barplot
  dev.copy2pdf(file = "path/to/barplots.table.2.pdf")
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @MaxGasner. That really helped a lot. I have an additional question: In the output now, beside the successfully displayed (and saved) plots, there is an additional output `.png`. I have now to click on the graph under the chunk to properly see it full scale. Does somebody know how to get rid of the `.png` so that the graph is directly output full scale under the chunk?

Comment: I just found an improvement: adding `dev.control(displaylist ="inhibit")` after the `dev.copy2pdf(file = "path/to/barplots.table.2.pdf")` line. The `.png` output is Always here but now at least the full scale plot is the default displayed output under the chunk

Answer (score 10):

You can easily add arguments for `pdf` in the `dev.copy` call, like this:

```
create.barplots <- function(vec,dir,file)
 {
   windows()
   plot(vec)
   dev.copy(pdf,file=paste(dir,file,sep="/") 
   dev.off()
 }
```

`dev.copy()` has a ... argument to pass arguments to the pdf function, see also `?dev.copy`. Alternatively you can use `dev.copy2pdf` , as Max told you. I'd also advise you to use `windows()` instead of `x11()`, otherwise you might have trouble with the font families. The defaults for x11 and pdf don't always match.

To save a file in another directory, just add the full directory (eg with paste, like in the function above)

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057782/is-there-a-way-to-push-an-r-script-file-into-a-sweave-document-opposite-of-tang/8059532#8059532), you may consider my `knitr` package; if you use it in an interactive R session, you will be able to see the plots in a window and save them to pdf without any hacks (it is the default behavior). I still need a lot of efforts on the [documentation](http://bit.ly/knitr-main) and demos, but it should be able to work with an Rnw document. The main reason that you can both see the plots and save them in `knitr` is, `knitr` is very different with Sweave in design -- the graphical device is opened *after* the code is evaluated, so your plots will not be hidden in an off-screen device. Again, I need to warn you that it is highly experimental at the moment.

Comment: Worth noting that, a few year later, `knitr` is one of the most thoroughly documented packages.

Answer (score 0):

Following works nicely for me when called from inside functions.  Call it after the plot code:

```
pdf2 <- function (file = "plot.pdf", w = 10, h = 7.07, openPDF = FALSE) 
{
    dev.copy2pdf(file = file, width = w, height = h, out.type = "pdf")
    if(openPDF) browseURL(file)
}
```

NB. `openPDF` may only work in Windows with full (not relative) file path.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the answer by Max Gasner, I wrote this helper function which allows to quickly switch from displaying and not. The argument x is a plot object or the function that does the drawing.

```
savepdf<-function(x, file, display=TRUE) {
    if (display){
        x;
        dev.copy2pdf(file=file)
    }
    else {
        pdf(file=file)
        x;
        dev.off()
    }
}
```

Example:

```
savepdf(plot(c(1,2,3)), file="123.pdf", display=F)
```