# How to plot many plots to a pdf and AND a subset to Rmarkdown report?

Tags: r, pdf, plot, r-markdown

I need to generate about >50 plots. I want to save them all in one pdf and have just a few of them appear in my R markdown html output.

I can print many plots to a single pdf like this:

```
pdf("path/to/out.pdf")
for (sam in samples){
    plot(sam) # simplified stand-in for many lines of code
}
dev.off()
```

That puts one sample's plot on each page of a pdf that I can flip through later.

I want some of those plots to appear in my markdown, without duplicating the plot code.

I've tried:

```
pdf("path/to/out.pdf")
count=0
for (sam in samples){
    plot(sam) # simplified stand-in for many lines of code

    if (sample(1:10,1)==1){ #randomly select a few examples
        count = count + 1
        dev.copy(which=dev.prev()) # to revert back to the default device
        dev.set(dev.next()) # to resume printing to the same pdf
    }
}
dev.off()
```

With this, the pdf is correct and count is >0, but the plots do not appear in the markdown report.

I think something from the dev.copy() family will do what I want but I can't seem to make it work.  In other variants I tried, dev.print() complains about only printing from a screen device, or I get errors saying that I cannot copy to the same device, or cannot copy to a null device.

Similar questions (such as [Saving plot as pdf and simultaneously display it in the window (x11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058606/saving-plot-as-pdf-and-simultaneously-display-it-in-the-window-x11)) often want to do the reverse: print to screen a then to a pdf.  And they generally only deal with one plot.
I want to make several plots, and I want ALL of my plots to go to the pdf, but only a FEW to go to the Rmarkdown html report as an example of what is in the pdf.

I'm working on a mac using R 3.5.1, RStudio v1.1.456

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are generating pdf files from within your Rmd document. Just create those plot in a rmarkdown code chunk without plotting to a pdf devide.

Comment: How about storing the plots in a list?  That way you can save them all in your pdf but then only print the ones you want by the list index.

Comment: have u tried lattice package?

Comment: I am currently using base R.
In response to @saisaran, I have not tried to lattice package, does it have functions that would help in this?

Comment: In response to @aosmith, the list idea is helpful.  Thank you!
It looks like ggplot2 supports saving figures to a list.  The plots I have right now use base R. I tried using recordPlot() and replayPlot(), and that looks like a pretty good solution.  I can generate all plots in one loop (and just not show them in the html output) and save each plot to a list.  Another loop saves each plot to the pdf, and another chunk prints a handful of the plots from the list.  This is pretty good.  I think converting to ggplot2 to use that list implementation might be smoother (not sure yet).